# is it possible to write a utility function to parse this JSON format?

Tags: jquery

```
{
    "item": {
        "T1": [{
            "name": "Snacks",
                "T2": [{
                "name": "Popcorn",
                    "T3": [{
                    "name": "Packet",
                        "T4": [{
                        "leaf": [{
                            "name": "popcorn packet caramel",
                                "price": 20
                        }, {
                            "name": "popcorn packet cheese",
                                "price": 30
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Beverages",
                "T2": [{
                "name": "Pepsi",
                    "T3": [{
                    "name": "Bottle",
                        "leaf": [{
                        "name": "pepsi bottle 250ml",
                            "price": 50
                    }, {
                        "name": "pepsi bottle 350ml",
                            "price": 60
                    }]
                }, {
                    "name": "Can",
                        "leaf": [{
                        "name": "pepsi can 250ml",
                            "price": 50
                    }, {
                        "name": "pepsi can 100ml",
                            "price": 40
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

If you observe the above JSON each array has got the **name** attributefor it , except the **leaf** level

For example

T1 has got two names **Snacks and Beverages**

Snacks has got one name **Popcorn**

Popcorn has got one name **Packet**

==========================

Beverages has got two names **Pepsi**

Pepsi has got two names **Bottle and Can**

If a value is given , i have written a function this way to return the values

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var a = 0; a < jsondata.item.T1.length; a++) {
        if (jsondata.item.T1[a].name == 'Snacks') {
            for (var b = 0; b < jsondata.item.T1[a].T2.length; b++) {
                for (var c = 0; c < jsondata.item.T1[a].T2[b].T3.length; c++) {
                    for (var d = 0; d < jsondata.item.T1[a].T2[b].T3[c].T4.length; d++) {
                        for (var e = 0; e < jsondata.item.T1[a].T2[b].T3[c].T4[d].leaf.length; e++) {
                            console.log(jsondata.item.T1[a].T2[b].T3[c].T4[d].leaf[e].name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My question: is it possible to write a utility function which accepts a value and returns the values present for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a little bit of playing around, but this worked:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xrF9K/55/)**

```
function isArray(what) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(what) === '[object Array]';
}

function isObject(what) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(what) === '[object Object]';
}

var results = [];
var cancel = false;

function recursiveSearch(name, json, startSaving, parentJson) {
    if (cancel) return;
    if (startSaving) {
        if (parentJson["leaf"]) {
            results.push(parentJson["leaf"]);
            cancel = true; //pushing leaf twice for somereason, work around with 'cancel'
            return;
        } else if (json["leaf"]) {
            results.push(json["leaf"]);
            cancel = true; //pushing leaf twice for somereason, work around with 'cancel'
            return;
        } else if (json["name"]) {
            results.push(json["name"]);
            return;
        }
    }
    if (isArray(json)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            recursiveSearch(name, json[i], startSaving, json);
        }
    } else {
        if (isObject(json)) {
            for (key in json) {
                if (key == "name") {
                    if (json[key] == name) {
                        startSaving = true;
                    }
                } else if (key == name) {
                    startSaving = true;
                }
                recursiveSearch(name, json[key], startSaving, json);
            }
        }
    }
}

function search(name) {
    results = [];
    cancel = false;
    recursiveSearch(name, jsondata);
    console.log(results);
}

console.log('Search for "T1"');
search('T1');
console.log('Search for "T2"');
search('T2');
console.log('Search for "T3"');
search('T3');
console.log('Search for "Snacks"');
search('Snacks');
console.log('Search for "Popcorn"');
search('Popcorn');
console.log('Search for "Packet"');
search('Packet');
console.log('Search for "Beverages"');
search('Beverages');
console.log('Search for "Pepsi"');
search('Pepsi');
console.log('Search for "Bottle"');
search('Bottle');
console.log('Search for "Can"');
search('Can');
```

Comment: Thanks Micheal ,but the question was misunderstood or i was wrong . What exaclt i wanted is each array has got name under it , for example if T1 is given , i need the name present under it that is Snacks and Beverages  , similarly i give the value Snacks , it must return Popcorn

Comment: I still don't guess I understand. Maybe pseudo code the input and output you want. Like `search('T1') = ["snacks","beverages"]`

Comment: Also using the word 'value' is very confusing. Each of these Json objects have attribute-object/array/value relationships.  The name attribute has a value. Many of the other attributs are linked to objects or arrays. So editing your question to include a black box function and it's expected result will go a long way towards understanding your need.

Comment: You want multiple functions? I thought you wanted a utility function that could return everything. Based upon some parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55160/discussion-between-michael-b-and-kiran).

Comment: Hi Micheal , I was trying to use the utility function you provided , and i am struck up at one place . could you please see this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162582/javascript-generic-function-returning-wrong-result-for-one-of-the-input

Comment: It's the same problem we left off on..you have a different structure for how 'leafs' work in the new questions. You could add the leaves to a 'T4' like http://jsfiddle.net/xrF9K/62/  or you'd have to change the way the code looks at the 'parent' It is extremely important that you use the same structure for 'leaf' in every case. Otherwise, there's no way to build the search you are looking for.